# What is the difference between careers.SO, careers.joelonsoftware and careers.SF?

Tags: support, jobs

From what I'm seeing, the following three sites look exactly the same. I created a profile on only the first one, but I see I now have profiles on each of them. What is the difference between the sites? Is there any case when I should prefer one over another?

1. http://careers.stackoverflow.com
2. http://careers.joelonsoftware.com
3. http://careers.serverfault.com

Comment: Did you happen to notice that Careers.SF redirects *immediately* to Careers.SO?

Comment: Aha! I just saw that. But careers.joelonsoftware does not redirect.

Comment: Interesting find! I just spent a couple minutes on careers.joelonsoftware. It provides the exact same search results as careers.SO, and the page title even says "Stack Overflow."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay. I am answering my own question. Here are the difference of the 3 sites. Though its not approved by [Joel](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky) or [Jeff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood).

### Stackoverflow careers 2.0

- Job seeker can manipulate their profile.
- Employers can search for potential candidate

### Joel on software careers

- Job seekers can not manipulate their profile. In fact there is not link for "my profile"
- Employers can not search profiles rather they can just post a job and wait for incoming applications

### Server fault Careers

- Please read **Stackoverflow careers 2.0**  section above. (*careers.SF redirects to careers.SO, so I am redirecting you too*)

From Joels blog, (note the links)

> You can [search job listings](http://careers.joelonsoftware.com/) or even [file a CV](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) and let employers find you.

Comment: +1 for the very clever redirect

Answer (score -1):

According to whois, joelonsoftware.com is owned by fogcreek.com <s>and I cannot imagine they are related to StackOverflow at all. They may be mirroring the layout of Careers (and also using the same data source from Careers) for their own purposes.</s>

From http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/04/16.html, he is the co-founder of SO. So that site may be part of the SO network, or something he uses for testing.

For the others you listed, most likely any SO domain using the `careers` subdomain will redirect to the correct address (careers.stackoverflow.com).

The preferred site to use is http://careers.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Joel on Software predates Stack Overflow. Joel was already a somewhat famous blogger when he and Jeff came up with SO; the first SO users were mostly if not entirely drawn from the readerships of Joel on Software and Coding Horror.

Answer (score -4):

They are one and the **SAME** site, just a different logo (no idea why).

[image]

Comment: The OP already knows the sites _look_ the same, so backing your statement up with screenshots seems unhelpful at best and snippy/rude at worst, regardless of the freehandedness of your arrows.

Comment: @PopularDemand the OP asked for the difference. I said that there is **none**, they are the same exact site.