# Isn't that the style of Stack Overflow Careers at careers.joelonsoftware.com?

Tags: discussion, jobs, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between careers.SO, careers.joelonsoftware and careers.SF?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133378/what-is-the-difference-between-careers-so-careers-joelonsoftware-and-careers-sf)

Please checkout this design, doesn't it look like the Stack Overflow careers - did they steal the design or something?

http://careers.joelonsoftware.com/jobs

they stole the design of Stack Overflow careers or what?

Answer (score 10):

It is the other way around.

[Joel](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky) is one of the founders of Stack Overflow. His jobs site predates Stack Overflow and is/was used as the basis of Stack Overflow careers search and listing.

Comment: Oh , I got it , sorry I didn't know that

Comment: No need to be sorry - not everyone knows everything ;)

Comment: God only knows everything